# PROGMEM error on MacOS High Sierra Arduino Mac 1.8.5

Tags: arduino, esp8266, esp32, progmem

I'm using MacBook Pro running on MacOS High Sierra.

There is a problem whenever i tried to upload Arduino code containing PROGMEM
to store raw HTML string (**Arduino Mac 1.8.5**) to my ESP board.
The board that i'm using is ESP8266 LoLin V3.

**Exception (3)** is raised in the Serial Monitor whenever i access
the IP address of the ESP on the web browser.
I've also tried to upload the same exact code using Windows version of **Arduino for Windows**(1.8.5)
and the webpage can be displayed perfectly fine.

Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

const char *ssid = "ssid";
const char *password = "password";

ESP8266WebServer server ( 80 );

const char homepage[] PROGMEM = R"(
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <h1>Mac can't compile PROGMEM properly!</h1>
  <h3>try to upload this code to any ESP8266 on a Mac and see the error!</h3>
  <h3>Exception (3)
  LoadStoreErrorCause
  Processor internal physical address or data error during load or store!</h3>
  <h3>Windows can easily compile this and read the file perfectly on ESP8266!</h3>
  </body>
  </html>
)";

void handleRoot() {
  String page = homepage;
  server.send(200, "text/html", page); //Send web page
}

void setup ( void ) {
    Serial.begin ( 115200 );
    WiFi.mode ( WIFI_STA );
    WiFi.begin ( ssid, password );
    Serial.println ( "" );
    // Wait for connection
    while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
        delay ( 500 );
        Serial.print ( "." );
    }
    Serial.println ( "" );
    Serial.print ( "Connected to " );
    Serial.println ( ssid );
    Serial.print ( "IP address: " );
    Serial.println ( WiFi.localIP() );

    if ( MDNS.begin ( "esp8266" ) ) {
        Serial.println ( "MDNS responder started" );
    }
    server.on ( "/", handleRoot );
    server.begin();
    Serial.println ( "HTTP server started" );
}

void loop ( void ) {
    server.handleClient();
}
```

Error raised is as follows:

```
Exception (3):
epc1=0x40209d64 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x4023ad32 depc=0x00000000

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffefb20 end: 3ffefe10 offset: 01a0

>>>stack>>>
3ffefcc0:  3ffe8b02 3ffeea80 3ffefd00 40207729
3ffefcd0:  00000001 00000001 3ffefd00 40207776
3ffefce0:  4023ad32 3ffefd40 3ffefd40 402076ab
3ffefcf0:  3fff10d4 00000001 3fff1044 4020206e
3ffefd00:  3fff118c 0000018f 00000182 4010020c
3ffefd10:  00000001 00000001 3ffefd40 4020836e
3ffefd20:  00000000 00000000 3fff1044 40204406
3ffefd30:  3fff1044 3ffeea9c 3fff1044 40204442
3ffefd40:  00000000 00000000 00000000 40207858
3ffefd50:  3fff1044 3ffeea9c 3ffeea58 402044c9
3ffefd60:  3fff10d4 0000000f 00000001 00000000
3ffefd70:  00000000 00000013 3ffeea5c 40203058
3ffefd80:  3ffeea9c 00000001 3ffeedf0 3ffeea80
3ffefd90:  00000001 00000000 40203964 0000000a
3ffefda0:  00000000 3fff0e5c 3ffeea58 3ffeeddc
3ffefdb0:  00000001 3ffeea80 3ffeea58 402046c0
3ffefdc0:  40107058 00000000 00001388 40208364
3ffefdd0:  00000000 3fff0e5c 00000000 feefeffe
3ffefde0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeedd4 402021d0
3ffefdf0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeedd4 402080e4
3ffefe00:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffeedf0 40100710
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v614f7c32
~ld
```

Can anyone here using a Mac try to upload the code on your ESP8266 and see if you get the same error as mine?
Can anyone with a good knowledge on PROGMEM and ESP8266 help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program you have

```
void handleRoot() {
  String page = homepage;
  server.send(200, "text/html", page); //Send web page
}
```

This should be

```
void handleRoot() {
  String page = FPSTR(homepage);
  server.send(200, "text/html", page); //Send web page
}
```

Add the `FPSTR()` and it will work properly. Without it your program can't properly dereference the string that you stored in Flash.

You can find more about this at https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I’ll try that method soon. As for now I’m using SPIFFS method to store HTML code which works just fine on Mac.